# Database mirroring

Tags: sql-server, database, database-mirroring

I'm designing a CRM for a company with 3 branches. the connection between these 3 branches is not reliable (with a vpn over internet). so we decided to setup a local server with SqlServer Database in each one and configure these DBs in the way that whenever a client inserted data into any of these DBs it automatically insert it into other ones. How could I do this?
and my programming language is C# if it would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SQL Server replication, more specifically Merge Replication

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx